# How can I search and replace values in a VBA array?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I just asked a question here yesterday (thanks again!) but hopefully it's alright if I ask another. 
At the end of my current VBA Macro, I have an array with URLs / Links in it. I'm trying to search and replace a part that's common to all the URLs, and I'm getting an error with my current code to do that. 
Here is my current Macro without the added part, it does its job quite well and creates an array and scrapes the URLs in it.

```
 Sub GetData()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim itemEle As Object
    Dim upvote As Integer, awards As Integer, animated As Integer
    Dim postdate As String, upvotepercent As String, oc As String, filetype As String, linkurl As String, myhtmldata As String, visiComments As String, totalComments As String, removedComments As String
    Dim y As Integer

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = False

    IE.navigate (ActiveCell.Value)
    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long, urls(), results(), results2()

    Set nodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll(".comments")
    ReDim urls(0 To nodeList.Length - 1)
    ReDim results(1 To nodeList.Length, 1 To 5)
    'Store all urls in an array to later loop
    For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
        urls(i) = nodeList.Item(i).href
    Next

    For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
        IE.Navigate2 urls(i)    'opens in a new tab
        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        results(i + 1, 1) = IE.document.querySelector("a.title").innerText 'title
        results(i + 1, 2) = IE.document.querySelector(".number").innerText 'upvotes
        upvotepercent = IE.document.querySelector(".word").NextSibling.NodeValue  '%
        results(i + 1, 3) = CDbl(Mid(upvotepercent, 3, 2)) / 100
        results(i + 1, 4) = IE.document.querySelector("div.date > time").innerText
    Next
```

This is where my problem is. All URLs/values in that array have "old.reddit.com" in them, and I'm trying to replace that with "removeddit.com". I've added this code to it and it's not doing the job even though to my understanding, I'm using the Replace function correctly - I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error at the `url(rw, col) = Replace`  line.

The part that's giving an error is the first one. (second part is supposed to scrape two values from each of the new URLs using the same method than for the original URLs, but right now the first one is the issue - or so I think, sometimes the debugger isn't very clear).

```
tofind = "old.reddit.com"
toreplace = "removeddit.com"
For rw = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
    For col = LBound(urls, 1) To UBound(urls, 1)
        urls(rw, col) = Replace(urls(rw, col), tofind, toreplace)
    Next
Next


For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
    IE.Navigate2 urls(i)    'opens in a new tab
    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    visiComments = IE.document.querySelector(".removed-text").innerText 'title
    results(i + 1, 5) = visiComments
Next
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

I feel like I'm trying stuff that's too advanced, considering I just got into VBA, so any and all pointers would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks! :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `For col = LBound(urls, 2) To UBound(urls, 2)` ?

Comment: That said, `urls` seems to be a 1d array?

Comment: If your values are strings and your array is 1D and the text you need to find is unique in the url then you can join separating with a ',' to get a single string, replace to replace the unique text, then split at "," to get back an array of url which have been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have create a **zero-based one-dimensional** array.  Here is an example of changing all the elements of that array:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim url(0 To 2) As String

    Dim U As Long, L As Long, i As Long, a
    url(0) = "xLarry"
    url(1) = "nothing"
    url(2) = "111Larry"

    L = LBound(url)
    U = UBound(url)
    For i = L To U
        url(i) = Replace(url(i), "Larry", "Moe")
    Next i

    msg = ""
    For Each a In url
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & a
    Next a
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]